# Sqlite3 insert statement error

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I am trying to insert the following into my sqlite3 database:

```
INSERT INTO candlestick_1min (timestamp, close, high, low, open, volume) 
VALUES (2016-08-11 15:30:00, 34.258, 34.318, 34.258, 34.302, 45890.0);
```

For some reason it's giving me the following error:

```
Error: near "15": syntax error
```

The schema is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE candlestick_1min (timestamp TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, close    REAL, high REAL, low REAL, open REAL, volume REAL);
```

Can anybody tell me why the error is showing up? The table is completely empty by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the date values inside quotes `''` like

```
INSERT INTO candlestick_1min (timestamp, close, high, low, open, volume) 
VALUES ('2016-08-11 15:30:00', 34.258, 34.318, 34.258, 34.302, 45890.0);
```